# How to slow down only one edge of a pulse?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency

I'd like to make the rise time and fall time of a logic signal be different.   I have a microcontroller pin driving a 10pF load as push-pull.  If driven directly the rise and fall times are both around 1.5 ns

I can change the rise and fall time by putting a resistor in between, for example 3 kohm gives around 30ns for both rise and fall.  What I'd like to do though is to slow down the fall times only.  I tried putting a diode in parallel with the resistor, and somewhat to my surprise the fall time is still short.  This is with a 1N914 and a 1N5711 both of which are pretty fast as diodes go.

How can I slow down the fall times only?  Would the diode idea work for some choice of diode, and why isn't it working for the ones I tried?

Comment: Did you put the diode the right way around?

Comment: Yes!  Also, the rise and fall time is still just as fast with the diode as when driven direct... even if I put it in backwards I'd expect it to slow down one edge

Comment: Then perhaps the diode you have used has too much reverse recovery time. Have you tried a BAS16 for instance. It is the fastest of the commonly available diodes but it has a reverse recovery time of 4 ns (from memory) and this still makes it partially unsuitable for your application.

Comment: Can you change the microcontroller code? Instead of driving it push-pull, drive it high/tristate and put a pulldown resistor. Cheap.

Comment: So you want rise time 1.5ns, fall time 30ns? Which micro? What is the pin driving? Would a slightly longer rise time be acceptable? (and if not, why not?).

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to state just why you need to have the asymmetrical rise and fall times. Sometimes the problem you think you are trying to solve has a better method of solution than what you are thinking about.

Comment: That's the way the MOSFET/IGBT driver do. It can't be understood why you have the same times. Could be that diode isn't suitable. You can even try with JFET transistor PN4117A as diode, it has very low leakage current.

Comment: As PN4117A i not more available, you can use MMBF4117 as a replacement. 100fA to 10pA max. leakage current, fast recovery, while the BAS diodes have more than 1nA leakage, while the 1N5711 has 200nA leakage.

Comment: You should consider driving the load using two separate pins on the microcontroller -- one configured to pull up only, and the other configured to pull down only. The latter one would be connected through your resistor. If the two pins are on the same port, it should be possible to switch them on/off simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're inferring the rise-fall times by looking at the output of a gate or whatever rather than trying to measure the voltage across the 10pF directly. I also assume you're trying to **delay** the signal at the output not to change the rise-fall times- because a gate has a great deal of voltage gain (especially a buffered gate) the rise-fall times at the output will be fast even for relatively slow input rise-fall times.

A 1N914/1N4148 has a fair bit of capacitance (~4pF at 0V). Maybe you can parallel the load with (say) 100pF and reduce the resistor value to 270\$\Omega\$.

Or use a *small* PIN or Schottky diode with little capacitance. Eg. [SMS3925-040LF](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/SMS3925_040LF_200132K.pdf) from Skyworks (0.48pF @ 0V). Or do both.

Obviously layout is important at relatively low capacitance levels.

Comment: Thanks!  I've measured the rise-fall times both indirectly and directly, with an active probe.  The small Schottky suggestion sounds excellent - I don't have one here yet but I tried it in Spice and it works.   Perhaps the Schottky I was trying was just too big (high capacitance) for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the MMBF4117 JFET as a diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDtoS0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why a JFET as diode? BTW: your CMOS pair is wrong (P-MOS at bottom, N-NOS at top).

Comment: @Curd 1.Because it has less leakage current. 2. I don't think so. Do you have any proof, that it has to be swapped?

Comment: @Curd You are correct. MCU has  N-MOS at bottom, P-MOS at top.